# How to get Android Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL trigger every 5minutes when user dwells in a geofence

Tags: android, geolocation, geocoding, android-location, android-geofence

I tried setting initial trigger to INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER as well as INITIAL_TRIGGER_DWELL. Whichever i set , that trigger will be called once and i get one notification.

```
private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}
```

I also added  setLoiteringDelay(5000) for 5 second delay. 
As per the documentation-

> Sets the delay between GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER and
>   GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELLING in milliseconds. For example, if
>   loitering delay is set to 300000 ms (i.e. 5 minutes) the geofence
>   service will send a GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL alert roughly 5 minutes
>   after user enters a geofence if the user stays inside the geofence
>   during this period of time. If the user exits from the geofence in
>   this amount of time, GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL alert won't be sent.

Correct me if i am wrong, from my understanding setting this should trigger every 5minutes. I have set to 5 seconds, so it is supposed to trigger dwell event every 5 seconds. Am I missing something here? Please let me know thank you.

**Update:**

I searched all over the net for couple of days but this is what i could find as of now. This may not be right way of doing but it does what it is supposed to do.

Check the sample project which i have created- https://github.com/SkyTreasure/am-i-in-the-geofencing

Let me know if anyone finds a better solution.